# Comparing two big lists (more than 100k) in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, stream, java-stream

I want to compare two big string lists faster in java which are not of equal size. I want to know is there any better way to improve performance.

I see performance issue in

```
List<String> list1 = 100k records 
List<String> list2 = 10 million records;

#method1 used removeAll
list1.removeAll(list2);

method2 used java8 streams
List<String> unavailable = list1.stream()
                    .filter(e -> (list2.stream()
                            .filter(d -> d.equals(e))
                            .count())<1)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I am trying to get records which are in `list1` and not exists in `list2`.

Comment: what do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: Most people in the Western world have no idea that 1 lakh means 100K.

Comment: I believe you meant *lakh*, where *10 lakhs = 1 million*. Apart from that stream is not relatively faster than iterating with a `for` loop. Another point to add, what are you trying to do with the comparison?

Comment: And yes, your requirements are unclear. What do you intend to achieve. Your method 1 and method 2 will result in something very different. The first one modifies list1, the second one creates a new list. So: what is the exact goal you want to achieve?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to ensure that all the items in the first list are in the second list? In that case, you should create a set from the second list and use `contains`.

Comment: Your goal is unclear. Please take more care when authoring a Question.

Comment: @fuzious.. I am trying to get records which are in list1 and not exists in list2.

Comment: Where do you get your numbers for the so-called "performance issues"? There is no sense in spending time in optimization if it's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do to improve the performance is to use `Set`s instead of `List`s, because they have *O(1)* for `Set.contains()`. But therefore you should not care about duplicates in your lists.

If you don't care about the order oft the items use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), otherwise use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). Using sets it nearly doesn't matter if you use `Set.removeAll()` or `Stream.filter()`, because `removeAll()` uses `contains()` internally.

So you can eiter use this if you need a new set and don't want to touch the orginal:

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
Set<String> unavailable = list1.stream()
        .filter(e -> !set2.contains(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you want a list as result use `Collectors.toList()` instead:

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
List<String> unavailable = list1.stream()
        .filter(e -> !set2.contains(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Use this if you just want to remove the items from `list1`:

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
list1.removeAll(set2);
```

Or even shorter:

```
list1.removeAll(new HashSet<>(list2));
```

Comment: Thank you @Samuel Philipp, I see much more improvement in performance now using set.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> unavailable = list1.stream()
                                .filter(e -> !list2.contains(e))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(or)

```
List<String> unavailable = list1.stream() 
                                .filter(not(list2::contains)) 
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

create predicate as below

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> t) {
        return t.negate();
    }
```

Comment: Java 11 has already [`Predicate.not()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) but beside that, your answer will net improve the performance.